# Checking if phone numbers in contact list is registered with us or not taking very long time (more than 1 minute)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app which has group chat support. In the app I am displaying a contact list to choose the contact from. Here I want to show those contacts first with header as "Choose to add in group" who is already registered with us then show rest contacts (who is not registered with us) with header as "Choose to invite". Same as WhatsApp contact list.

I am using Firebase database. I have already implemented it but the problem is it take's ages to syncronize the contacts if it is registered or not then populates listView. It takes more than a minute to syncronize. I can not use this method, it need to be fast. Also I want to add those headers.

In my code I am checking each phone number one by one in database.

**Here is the code for checking contacts.**

Here `contact[1]` is mobile number and `contact[0]` is name.

```
private HashMap filterRegisteredAndUnregisteredUser(ArrayList<String[]> contacts){
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        final ArrayList<String[]> registeredUser = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String[]> unRegisteredUser = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("numbers");
        for (final String[] contact : contacts){
            database.child(contact[1]).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        registeredUser.add(contact);
                    }else{
                        unRegisteredUser.add(contact);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
        hashMap.put("registeredUser", registeredUser);
        hashMap.put("unRegisteredUser", unRegisteredUser);
        return hashMap;
    }
```

Then I am using these two lists `registeredUser` and `unRegisteredUser` in adapter to populate list.

**Here is the code for adapter.**

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<String[]> contactList;
    private ArrayList<String[]> registeredContact;
    private ArrayList<String[]> unRegisteredContact;
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;
    private Activity context;
    private ArrayList<String[]> selectedContact = new ArrayList<>();
    private int personCounter = 0;

    public ContactListAdapter(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap){
        this.context = (Activity) hashMap.get("context");
        this.actionBar = (android.support.v7.app.ActionBar) hashMap.get("actionBar");
        this.registeredContact = (ArrayList<String[]>) hashMap.get("registeredUser");
        this.unRegisteredContact = (ArrayList<String[]>) hashMap.get("unRegisteredUser");
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        if (position > registeredContact.size()-1){
            position -= registeredContact.size();
            return unRegisteredContact.get(position);
        }else {
            return registeredContact.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return registeredContact.size() + unRegisteredContact.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
        final String[] contact;
        if (position > registeredContact.size()-1){
            int newPosition = position - registeredContact.size();
            contact = unRegisteredContact.get(newPosition);
        }else {
            contact = registeredContact.get(position);
        }
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (view == null){
            view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, null);
            holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            holder.image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_pic);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            if (selectedContact.contains(contact)){
                view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.personSelectBackground));
            }else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.fui_transparent));
            }
        }

        String[] extractName = contact[0].split(" ");
        String firstName = extractName[0];
        String textAsImage;
        if (extractName.length > 1){
            String lastName = extractName[extractName.length -1];
            textAsImage = Character.toString(firstName.toCharArray()[0])
                    + Character.toString(lastName.toCharArray()[0]);
        }else {
            textAsImage = Character.toString(firstName.toCharArray()[0]);
        }

        TextDrawable textDrawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .beginConfig()
                .toUpperCase()
                .endConfig()
                .buildRound(textAsImage, ColorGenerator.DEFAULT.getColor(contact[1]));
        holder.name.setText(contact[0]);
        holder.image.setBackground(textDrawable);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!selectedContact.contains(contact)) {
                    selectedContact.add(contact);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.personSelectBackground));
                    Toast.makeText(context, contact[0]+" selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    personCounter++;
                }else {
                    selectedContact.remove(contact);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.fui_transparent));
                    Toast.makeText(context, contact[0]+" removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    personCounter--;
                }
                setActionBar();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void setActionBar(){
        if (personCounter != 0){
            if (personCounter == 1){
                actionBar.setTitle(personCounter + " Person selected.");
            }else {
                actionBar.setTitle(personCounter + " Persons selected.");
            }
        }else {
            actionBar.setTitle(context.getTitle());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getSelectedContact(){
        return selectedContact;
    }
}
```